Reply to email with nodemailer
I'm trying to replay an email with nodemailer in node.js, but I can't.
It always generate a new thread instead of reply to the original email.
EDIT:
I'm visualizing the emails in Outlook and it's not working there, but if I view the emails in Gmail and don't specify the messageId, if they have the same subject they appear as replies. I'm looking for a solution that works on any email client.
This is my code:
async function sendEmail(idMessage) {
    try {
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'mail.test.es',
            port: 25,
            secure: false,
            ignoreTLS: true,
            auth: {
                user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
                pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
            },
        });
       
        let mailOptions;
        if (idMessage) {
            console.log("idMessage:",idMessage)
            mailOptions = {
                from: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
                to: process.env.EMAIL_2,
                subject: 'test',
                html: `<p>Test:</p>`,
                inReplyTo: idMessage,
                references: `[${idMessage}]`,
            };
        }else{
            mailOptions = {
                from: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
                to: process.env.EMAIL_2,
                subject: 'test',
                html: `<p>Test:</p>`
            };
        }
        console.log("mailOptions",mailOptions)
        const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        console.log('Response:', info.response);
        console.log('info:', info);
        console.log('id:', info.messageId); 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error', error);
    }
}

first I send an email without idMessage, and I get this:
mailOptions {
  from: 'myemail@test.es',
  to: 'email@test.es',
  subject: 'test',
  html: '<p>Test:</p>'
}
Response: 250 OK id=1s7AyX-0000000Dhau-4Ab4
info: {
  accepted: [ 'email@test.es' ],
  rejected: [],
  ehlo: [
    'STARTTLS',
    'SIZE 52428800',
    '8BITMIME',
    'AUTH PLAIN LOGIN',
    'SIZE 52428800',
    'HELP'
  ],
  envelopeTime: 202,
  messageTime: 110,
  messageSize: 280,
  response: '250 OK id=1s7AyX-0000000Dhau-4Ab4',
  envelope: { from: 'myemail@test.es', to: [ 'email@test.es' ] },
  messageId: '<92678bda-5a53-f350-a267-d4d6278c50b1@test.es>'
}
id: <92678bda-5a53-f350-a267-d4d6278c50b1@test.es>

At the moment is working well, but when I call the function with the messageId:
sendEmail('<92678bda-5a53-f350-a267-d4d6278c50b1@test.es>');
I get this:
idMessage: <92678bda-5a53-f350-a267-d4d6278c50b1@test.es>
mailOptions {
  from: 'myemail@test.es',
  to: 'email@test.es',
  subject: 'test',
  html: '<p>Test:</p>',
  inReplyTo: '<92678bda-5a53-f350-a267-d4d6278c50b1@test.es>',
  references: '[<92678bda-5a53-f350-a267-d4d6278c50b1@test.es>]'
}
Response: 250 OK id=1s7B2d-0000000DiGI-2H7V
info: {
  accepted: [ 'email@test.es' ],
  rejected: [],
  ehlo: [
    'STARTTLS',
    'SIZE 52428800',
    '8BITMIME',
    'AUTH PLAIN LOGIN',
    'SIZE 52428800',
    'HELP'
  ],
  envelopeTime: 208,
  messageTime: 112,
  messageSize: 409,
  response: '250 OK id=1s7B2d-0000000DiGI-2H7V',
  envelope: { from: 'myemail@test.es', to: [ 'email@test.es' ] },
  messageId: '<be102611-052b-5a4d-5448-8ec5d421c458@test.es>'
}
id: <be102611-052b-5a4d-5448-8ec5d421c458@test.es>

But is generating a new thread instead of a reply

Check advanced fields references type is an array or space separated string. Try references: [idMessage] or references: `${idMessage}`

Thank you, I tried but is not working

"I'm looking for a solution that works on any email client" - I don't think this is 100% possible, how the e-mails are displayed/grouped is entirely up to the client
